# CSS Sticky footer issue

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I am trying to implement the CSS sticky footer on the following page:

http://www.tuhdoo.com/test/index.htm

As you can see it works to a point but there is a 20px overhang at the bottom of the screen that causes scrolling (firefox).

Can anyone help please?

I was following this tutorial:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: is there any reason you don't use position:fixed?

Comment: Because it is a CMS and the content is dynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is caused by the `padding-top:20px` on your body element. Try moving it to your `body > #container > header` element instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have a padding-top of 20px on the body element. This makes the height of the body element full screen plus 20px.

remove it and you'll be good :)